# Non-visual components not aligning correctly

Tags: delphi

Is there a way to make all the non-visual components on a form align correctly?

I know I can hold Ctrl+Arrow on the form designer to move them, but I just wish they would line up correctly by default.

I like to put the non-visual components grouped next to each other, they don't seem to line up properly though.

I know, it's not a technical question but this drives me mad!

Comment: There's also the `Arrange Non-visual Components` if you have [`CnPack`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cnwizards/) suite installed. This allows you to arrange all of the non visual controls to a grid with the specified row/col count, spacing and it can even sort them by the class name in a second.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can right-click on a component, or a group of selected components, and choose to Align them to the Form Designer's grid.

Comment: great thanks, i don't know why they don't normally line up :)